# Ensuring no duplicates without unique constraint

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to ensure that a column doesn't contain duplicate values **without using a UNIQUE constraint** (don't want to go in to the reasons for why this is being avoided) on that column? In particular I am thinking of race conditions.

For the sake of simplicity let's say that the column in question is of type `nvarchar(50)` (does the type even matter?)

Comment: If you want to _ensure_ no duplicate values I would use a unique constraint. You could use a trigger to perform a select statement before an insert or update but this will bite you in terms of performance and maintainability

Comment: It would actually be helpful if you were to tell us why you can't simply use a UNIQUE constraint or index. It may give us information that might lead to different angles on the problem.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen There are no deep-seated or complicated technical reasons for this, just orders from on high, and I'd rather not argue with them :-)...

Answer (score 2):

It is possible by a trigger, condition `If Not Exists(...` before insert. But in fact `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` the fastest.

Another option is to create unique index on that column and this is supposed to be faster than trigger and condition.

If you don't want to add a unique constraint to your existing table, you can create additional table with this field `nvarchar (50)` and unique constraint on it. And insert value of this field in this new table before insert in your main table in transaction (inside insert statement or in a trigger).

Comment: What if some other invocation inserts value 'Sales' between the running of `IF NOT EXISTS(...` and `INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(N'Sales')`? AFAIK we cannot guarantee atomicity of `IF NOT EXISTS` and following `INSERT INTO`.

Comment: We can guarantee atomicity even in case which you described in the transaction with transaction isolation level READ COMMITED, it excludes the possibility of phantom read during the transaction, But it is better to use additional table and insert to it before insert to the main table in a transaction

Comment: @markvgti, A conditional insert technique will be vulnerable to race conditions in the `READ_COMMITTED` isolation level unless you use a more restrictive level or specify locking hints (e.g. WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) in the `IF EXISTS' subquery.  Note that unless the column is indexed, performance and concurrency will be very bad.  Can you create a unique index (if not unique constraint)?

Comment: @DanGuzman Thanks for info. Creating a unique index may not be possible either :-(. You are suggesting creating a unique index on that column?

Comment: @Dan Guzman Correct, it can cause races and locking, that's why I suggest using of  additional table with unique constraint and insert to both in a single transaction.

Comment: @markvgti, yes, I was suggesting a unique index.  If a unique index or constraint isn't possible, a non-unique index is needed to avoid a full scan of every row in the table.

Comment: @Dan Guzman Thanks for reminding us about unique index options, I've added it to the list of alternative options.